# Display specific data based on a click on specific item in a list

Tags: jquery, jsp, servlets

I'm running into a problem, where I want to display information about a specific item when it is clicked? The code I'm working with is JSP/servlet with jQuery. The part I'm having problem is retrieving that information based on click.

```
function data(response) {

var records = response.split('||');
var write = "";
for (var i = 0; i < records.length; i++) {
    var productdata = records[i].split('|');

    write += "<div class='listproducts'><input type='image' src='/image_upload/" + productdata[4] + "' width=" + "'100%' name='item' value='" + productdata[4] + "'/><br/>" + productdata[1] + "<br/> $" + productdata[3] + "</div>";
}

$("#pcontentcontainer").html(write);
$("[name='item']").on('click', function () {
    $("#pcontentcontainer").html($("[name='item']").val());
});
}
```

Better example:
List of products, and you click on a product and it displays all information about that product only.

Comment: And what's the problem?

Comment: It's returning the same value/info from the first item and not the value/info on the item that it's being clicked on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
$("[name='item']").on('click', function () {
    $("#pcontentcontainer").html($(this).val());
});
```